# When stopping EC2 instance, it starts again automatically listed separately, previous one changes to terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I stopped our main instance to create and run a new one for temporary purpose. As I'm using free tier, I stopped the main one, created a new one, then in the instances, three instances appeared
The new one, the old main one which was earlier marked as stopped now terminated and a new main one marked as running. I stopped it again and again it appeared, now it's showing me 4 instances.

[image]

This "Ejabberd" is the one I've created just now. The other ones appear on their own when I stop the running one. I'm new to AWS, I searched but couldn't find anything about this behavior, I read how to stop an instance on their own website. What I want to do now is to stop it unless I want to start it and stop the "Ejabbered" one.

**Edit** - As suggested by user @ceejayoz about the auto scaling group, I checked it and found that there's one enabled. I checked the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-enable-disable-scaling-policy.html) to turn it off and found out that mine consists no scaling policy.

So, I looked more into the options of it and found out group details. On my own, I changed the desired capacity and Minimum capacity to 0 so it won't bother when I stop my instance. It worked.

[image]

**But**, it changed my instance's status to terminated from stopped. I don't know how and why? Although, I recovered it back by re-changing the values of auto scaling group to original but why stopping an instance set it to terminated?

Comment: I'd bet you've got an auto-scaling group.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just googled the way to disable it, it says to disable the scaling policy but I've no scaling policy in that. Should I create a new one and then disable it?

Comment: You should update your question with the details of your auto-scaling group if you have one.

Comment: @ceejayoz Please have a look. It's a mess now.

Answer (score 4):

Your EC2 instance is managed by an Auto Scaling group.

EC2 instances that are managed by Auto Scaling may be launched and terminated at any time. It's goal is to preserve a number of **running instances** greater than (or equal to) the Minimum count, and less than (or equal to) the Maximum count.. ideally the Desired count.

If you stop your EC2 instance, then Auto Scaling deems your EC2 instance as "unhealthy" and terminates it. It then replaces it with a new EC2 instance that it considers "healthy". This restores the number of running instances back to the Desired count.

When you set your Auto Scaling group Desired count to 0, that told Auto Scaling that you didn't want any running instances. It then terminated instances until the running count was 0.

When you reset the Desired count back to 1, you told Auto Scaling you wanted one running instance, so it launched a new one.

Auto Scaling did exactly what you it's designed to do, and exactly what you told it to do.

Although there are exceptions to the rule, generally speaking:

- if you want to manually stop and start your EC2 instances, don't put them under Auto Scaling,
- and, if you modify the contents of your EC2 instances directly, don't put them under Auto Scaling.

I highly recommend reading up more about Auto Scaling, or don't use it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I also read the docs yesterday and understood these but now, should I delete the Auto Scaling? As I'd not created it, I absolutely remember but it's a good option to have. Can I backup it? or is it very easy to create if I ever need?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar "As I'd not created it" ... They don't appear like magic. Something you did most certainly created it. Work backward to how you created the EC2 instance in the first place and you'll probably find the creator. It may be another AWS service like Elastic Beanstalk. "should I delete the Auto Scaling?" ... Not without knowing what created it. If you delete it, it may just be re-created, or you may break something else. "Can I backup it?" ... No, you cannot backup an Auto Scaling configuration.

Comment: This means I'm stuck. I think it would be best to remove the 2nd instance after testing it for now. I'll have a look in EBS configuration as well. Thanks.